# Configure code cleanup profile to delete object initializer constructor parentheses

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis, object-initializers

How can I configure my code cleanup profile in Visual Studio 2019 to change this piece of code

```
new List<Alias>() { key }
```

to this one

```
new List<Alias> { key }
```

when I am running code cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in the **Code Style** section as you can see [in the editor config official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-language-conventions?view=vs-2019#expression-level-preferences)

The only option is for **dotnet_style_collection_initializer**

```
// dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// dotnet_style_collection_initializer = false
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
```

This will remove the `()` if it refactors from non-collection-initializers. There is not option to refactor if the initialization occurs with the collection initalizer with the `()` inline.